# Using class in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone I'm a beginner in MVC3. My question is about using class. I'm using web services to get parameter at this point I have no problem but my problem is I'm defining every connection in each controller method again and again so is there any shorcut ?

Here is an example:

```
public ActionResult BeyanListe()
        {

Services_building client = new Services_built();
            Services client_service = new Services();
            client_service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "service_test";
            client_service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "..";
            client_service.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "service_test";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "..";
            client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

return View()
}
```

As you can see top I have declared two times for clientcredentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that both service classes are derived from same interface, eg. IServices, then:

```
private void AssignCredentials(IServices services)
{
   services.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "service_test";
   services.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "..";
   services.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
}
```

and in your base method call AssignCredentials method.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make client_service and client protected or private members of the controller.
2. Move your initialization code to the constructor of the controller.
3. Use client_service and client in your actions as needed.

If you use this same pattern across multiple controllers you may want to consider creating a controller base class that handles this function.